# Expression is always true (when it isn't)

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I have a query in the form:

```
var fruits = (from p in fruitDB
              where (p.Fruit.FruitID == fruitID && p.Color.ColorID != null )
              select p.Color).Distinct();
```

VS 2010 gives me a blue underline and informs me "Expression is always true". Now granted I agree if the data in the database wasn't stuffed up, but in my case, I will get a null if I do not include the added statement for `!= null`

So is this a bug or based on rules set in my database schema? (even though the underlying data contradicts it)

Comment: What type is p.Color.ColorID? Is it a struct, class, or value type?

Comment: What is fruitDB? Collection, dataset table, database table? What's the type, and nullability rules, of `ColorID`?

Comment: It sounds to me like the DB is configured as nullable but the model (`ColorID`) isn't...?

Answer (score 2):

What type is Color.ColorID? Is it an integer? Should you be checking for p.Color != null?

Comment: This was my first thought as well. But then my second thought was, "Can you even compare `int` values to `null`?"

Comment: You get a compiler error along the lines of "The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value type of 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

Comment: @Domenic: it is legal because it is legal to compare two nullable ints. An int is implicitly convertible to a nullable int, and null is implicitly convertible to a nullable int, so the comparison operator on nullables is applicable. It's an unfortunate emergent behaviour from the overload resolution rules.

Answer (score 2):

Can you include the Entity diagram?

If Color is a table and ColorID is its primary key, it's not going to be nullable.  Maybe the foreign key in your first table is nullable but that's not what you are testing here.

Answer (score 0):

Is ColorID nullable? Should you be checking if p.Color.ColorID == 0 instead?